# Getting a specific item when iterating through an array in objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < result.count; i++) {        
    id myArrayElement = [result objectAtIndex:i];               
    NSLog(@"My Array Element equals: %@", myArrayElement);
}
```

This is working just fine for me. I am getting my data back in json. The problem is when I try to grab a specific element.

I want to be able to do this 
Example:

NSString *anyElement = myArrayElement.anyElement;

And return its value.

Comment: You want to access retrieved data as attributes, then you will have to create your own domain object with json dictionary as constructor parameter, then assign values from json dictionary to the object's attributes.

Comment: So my data comes back like this => [{'name':[{'property': 'someProperty', 'value':'someValue', 'anyElement:'someElementValue' }]}] So I just need to be able to reach inside and grab that value.

Comment: @senagl: NSString *property = myArrayElement[@"name"][0][@"property"]; // value for property attribute

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at Objective-C literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)(specifically the "array-style subscripting" section), you could do:

```
NSString *anyElement = myArrayElement[indexOfAnyElementYouWant];
```

Comment: This will return a undeclared identifier of 'indexOfAnyElementYouWant'

Comment: you need to replace "`indexOfAnyElementYouWant`" with whatever index you want to use, e.g. "`i`" or "`anyElement`" or `senagiIndex` or whatever....

Answer (score 0):

> for (NSString* str in result) {
>       if ([str isEqualToString:@"MyName"])  {
>       NSLog(@"My Array Element equals: %@", str ); break; } }